# Which preposition is to be used with the word "evidence"?

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Whiile Mr Modi said that Congress is trying to erase evidence on the attack.....

My personal preference would be to use "of" instead of "on" after the word "evidence".

Comment: It's a mistake.  It has to be "evidence of" something.  You should understand by now that *The Hindu* often has small mistakes.

Comment: @Kelvin, You are correct. You can post an answer to your own question :)

Comment: But I get that sense of confirmation only from you guys.  ☺☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Evidence of" [something] is correct**. You should say 'evidence of the attack' rather than 'evidence on the attack'.

There is a possible use of "evidence on", in the context of "I've got evidence on you" (colloquial) which means something like: I know something incriminating about you [and I'm threatening to use it against you].

Answer (score 0):

If Congress is pretending that the attack never happened, **evidence of** is correct, and I would not use any other phrase.

If Congress concedes that there was an attack, but is trying to suppress the details and shift blame, I might use **evidence on**; but I'd prefer **evidence relating to** as clearer, or at least more idiomatic (to an American).